# Any api equivalent to mac growl api but on windows?

Tags: winapi

http://growl.info/documentation/developer/introduction.php:
Growl is a system for posting notifications to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Growl, but for Windows: http://www.growlforwindows.com

libraries for several programming language and the documentation for the protocol it uses can be found here: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/developers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Nothing as popular as Grown on mac but the standard Win32 API to do notifications is [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx).  You can see a sample project here on codeproject: [Adding Icons to the System Tray](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx).

Comment: Well Growl is more high level than Win32 and more about hooking the system than just put an icon but thanks for answer.